# Automatically falling back to solid color when gradient is not supported

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

So, I'm working on a mobile app, and, as you know, the older phones don't support CSS gradients.

I'm wondering if there is a way to fall back to a solid color when a gradient is not supported?

P.S: I'm okay with javascript to detect the stuff... to...be detected. But please, **NO jQuery!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just need to write the solid one first and gradient second. So that the 2nd one overrides the 1st one if the browser supports it, otherwise it gets ignored.

```
.classname {
  background: value;
  background: linear-gradient(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot!!!